# Why is $(\hat{X}^\top \hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1}\hat{X}^T \hat{y} = \hat{X}^T (\hat{X} \hat{X}^T + \lambda n I)^{-1} \hat{y}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I was trying to show the following:

$$(\hat{X}^T \hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1}\hat{X}^T \hat{y} = \hat{X}^T (\hat{X} \hat{X}^T + \lambda n I)^{-1} \hat{y}$$

I was told to use the Singular Value Decomposition of $\hat{X} = U \Sigma V^T = \sum^{r}_{i=1} \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$. So I tried:

$$ (\hat{X}^T \hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1} \hat{X}^T \hat{y} = (\hat{X}^T \hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1} (U \Sigma V^T)^\top \hat{y} $$

$$ ((U \Sigma V^T)^T (U \Sigma V^T) + \lambda n I)^{-1} V \Sigma U^T \hat{y} = ((V \Sigma^2 V^T) + \lambda n I)^{-1} V \Sigma U^T \hat{y} $$

however after that step I got stuck and it wasn't entirely obvious for me how to proceed. There are a lot of things that are confusing me about how proceed:

1. First is that its not entirely clear to me that an inverse for $ (\hat{X}^T \hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1} = ((U \Sigma^2 V^T) + \lambda n I)^{-1}$ even exists.
2. Second, even if it was invertible (i.e. an inverse existed), I'm not aware of any rules for sum of matrices and inverses (I think they do for transposes $(A + B)^T = A^T + B^T$ but not sure for inverses and can't find anything useful).

Anyone has any idea how to proceed? Or how I could further uses the SVD to show the equality I'm trying to show?

Comment: You could simply multiply the two sides by $X^T X + \lambda nI$ from the left.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh note that we are trying to show the LHS of the equation is equal to the RHS. I'm not suppose to actually know that they are equal, so I am not sure how multiplying both sides by $\hat{X}^T X + \lambda n I $ from the left helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an $m\times k$ matrix. You have 
$$(X^T X + \lambda n I_m) X^T = X^T (X X^T + \lambda n I_k).$$ When $-\lambda n$ is not in the spectrum of $X^T X$ nor $X X^T$ (e.g. when $\lambda n >0$) then you may invert to get:
$$ X^T(X X^T + \lambda n I_k)^{-1} = (X^T X + \lambda n I_m)^{-1}X^T .$$

Comment: I don't understand, are you just discussing the invertibility of the middle section or are you providing a proof for the equivalence I asked about. I can't see how you actually proved my original question though.

Comment: Must admit that I am just proposing an elementary proof of the first statement  bypassing the SVD. Miller's response seems ok for the SVD argument.

Comment: I am totally ok with an alternative proof (I always love those!). I guess my initial follow up to your answer highlights that I as sad as it might be, I don't see how your response provides an alternative proof (I honestly thought you were just discussing the invertibility of $X^TX$ for some reason unknown to me). Do you mind explaining that a bit more? Sorry for being dense.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking for? Anyway, since both $XX^T$ and $X^TX$ are non-negative the matrices $XX^T + \lambda n I_k$ and $X^T X + \lambda n I_m$ are invertible at least for $\lambda n>0$ (one in ${\Bbb C}^k$, the other in ${\Bbb C}^m$. And you get the identity below by multiplying with the respective inverses. That's really all.

Comment: I'm still amazed at how you even noticed this. Want to share the insight? (I'm aware it might not be easy to share except that you noticed it, I'm just surprised because I probably wouldn't have come up with such a short and elegant solution).

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Something like: As I said in my very first remark I just multiplied with $X^T X + \lambda n I$ from the left to get rid of the inverse on the LHS. Then noticing that this factor commutes nicely with $X^T$ to cancel the other inverse. In the beginning I thought that we had to deal with square matrices but then realized this was not necessary. Finally the proof became simpler by omitting the factor $y$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\hat{X} = U\Sigma V^T$, then
$$
\hat{X}^T\hat{X} + \lambda n I =  V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T + \lambda n I = V(\Sigma^T\Sigma + \lambda n I)V^T
$$

Therefore, $(\hat{X}^T\hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1} = V(\Sigma^T\Sigma + \lambda n I)^{-1}V^T$. The matrix in brackets is invertible so long as $\lambda n \neq -\sigma^2$ for any singular value $\sigma$ in the spectrum of $\hat{X}$. Similarly,

$$
(\hat{X}\hat{X}^T + \lambda n I)^{-1} = U(\Sigma\Sigma^T + \lambda n I)^{-1}U^T
$$

Thus we have

\begin{align}
\hat{X}^T(\hat{X}\hat{X}^T + \lambda n I)^{-1} &= V\Sigma^T(\Sigma\Sigma^T + \lambda n I)^{-1}U^T\\
&= V(\Sigma^T\Sigma + \lambda n I)^{-1}\Sigma^TU^T\\
&= (\hat{X}^T\hat{X} + \lambda n I)^{-1}\hat{X}^T
\end{align}

So essentially, using the SVD reduces the problem to the special case of diagonal matrices.

Comment: I had a strong feeling that adding some diagonal matrix would change the singular values (or eigenvalues in square case), but I just couldn't remember how or why. Do you mind expanding on that since it seems to be the most important aspect I was missing?

Comment: I could follow it through, but the SVD is not really necessary here. I would prefer H. H. Rugh's answer as it is much more elegant.

Comment: I understand H.H.Rugh's answer, I agree its nicer. But at this point I also wanted to see what I was originally after. Do you might expanding? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I updated the solution as per your request.

Comment: even if this solution is not as elegant it gives good practice in different skills in linear algebra, starting from SVD, to inverses of diagonal matrices, products to form identities from orthogonal matrices, etc. It was fun, thanks! :)